# Apache headers show 302 instead of 301 despite .htaccess

Tags: apache, .htaccess

I cant seem to figure out why my .htaccess redirect rule is not matching with the curl results on manually testing.

I've got a .htaccess file which contains the following

```
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule .* https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
```

I would expect this rule to transfer all non-https traffic to the https address. And this works. However when I check with curl I see 302 instead of 301.

```
HTTP/1.1 302 Found
Date: Sat, 01 Jul 2017 23:19:40 GMT
Server: Apache/2
Location: https://example.com/
Content-Length: 207
Content-Type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1
```

I'm wondering why this is because I clearly state L,R=301 in the htaccess file.

Comment: Could it be affected by your vhost somehow?

Comment: Sorry for the late response Ethan. I had some internet problems. However it was indeed overwritten in de vhost configuration. Your tip helped me alot. Thanks!